# Problemas con fetch y javascript (CORS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, cors

Estoy ocupando React y ocupé para crear todo el código base "create-react-app", lo cual genera un servidor en `localhost:3000` para ver los avances que se van haciendo en la app.

El problema que tengo es que me aparece este error :

> "[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (v1, line 0)"

Tengo el acceso a la API, eso esta comprobado, pero lo que necesito es activar CORS en React. Intenté hacerlo por express, pero se siguen mandando las solicitudes por el localhost:3000(el server creado por create-react-app) y no por el server de express.

Entonces necesito hacer que las solicitudes del fetch se hagan con CORS, y el modo no-cors no me sirve, ya lo intenté también, porque necesito quedarme con el json que responde la solicitud.

Comment: debes acomodar tu backend , para que permite las solicitudes CORS

Comment: @JackNavaRow parece estar relacionado, pero no es un duplicado. Este es un problema aparte que tienen quienes usan `create-react-app` en modo desarrollo. Podría eventualmente ser resuelto con las indicaciones de la pregunta que hiciste, pero el equipo de React ha dispuesto de sus propias indicaciones para resolver este problema (que de por cierto, detallo en mi repuesta :D). Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuál es la llamada que haces que te da ese problema?

Comment: Tienes acceso a la API? ya que la api deberia enviar los encabezados correctos para que el host en este caso localhost:3000 pueda acceder sin problemas con peticiones fetch. ¡En que lenguaje esta la api?

Comment: @vcasas Si tengo acceso a la API, eso lo comprobé ya, también se envían los encabezados, cuando pongo red en el buscador aparecen los encabezados y no hay problema, la API esta hecha por una página anexa a mi no sé en que lenguaje estará escrita, pero lo que si es que los datos retornar en JSON y tiene compatibilidad con javascript.

Comment: @AlterLagos dónde esta tu respuesta? para leerla ? Entonces tu recomiendas empezar a escribir react desde cero y no con el create-react-app?

Comment: @FelipeCorreaKusjanovic no entiendo a que te refieres donde está mi respuesta, pues aquí mismo en tu pregunta pero [un poco más abajo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285461/problemas-con-fetch-y-javascript-cors#285470). Y no se si me preguntaste a mí o si lo dedujiste de algo que dije, pero no, nunca te he recomendado empezar desde cero.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas [crear un proxy para ambiente de desarrollo](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development). 
Para esto, agrega a tu `package.json`:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:xxxx",
```

donde `xxxx` es el puerto de tu API. Luego, tanto los requests a la API como los de tu frontend, apuntarán al mismo puerto.

Comment: Para ambiente productivo seguirá el problema...

Comment: @vcasas es probable, pero el OP preguntó por el problema que tiene en ambiente de desarrollo, no en producción.